# Error loading TensorFlow SavedModel exported from GCP Vertex AI (maybe due to missing variables folder)

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've exported a TensorFlow model from Google Cloud's Vertex AI platform. The exported model contains only the saved_model.pb file and is missing the variables folder that typically accompanies TensorFlow SavedModels (I'm new to TF so sorry if the variables folder actually isn't important).

With Netron (since the version is nowhere to be found on GCP..) I checked the Tensorflow version that GCP uses which is (strangely) TensorFlow v2.14.0, this is still a release candidate.

Since I can open the model with Netron and I exported the model multiple times I assume the pb file itself is valid and not corrupted.

When trying to load this model using tf.saved_model.load(), I encounter the following error:

```
OSError: Cannot parse file b'/app/saved_model.pb': Error parsing message.
```

Steps taken:

- I've verified that the saved_model.pb is present in the correct directory.
- Attempted to load the model using TensorFlow 2.14.0rc0.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.14.0rc0
```

Python (also tried in Kotlin same thing):

```
import tensorflow as tf
...
model = tf.saved_model.load("/app/")
...
```

Does anyone know why the variables folder might be missing from a model exported from Vertex AI? Or if it has nothing to do with that, can someone give me some pointers to resolve this issue?

Steps taken:

- I've verified that the saved_model.pb is present in the correct directory.
- Attempted to load the model using TensorFlow 2.14.0rc0.

Comment: Also created a support ticket with GCP regarding the TF version.